# Google Maps API queryautocomplete location parameter doesn't work

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use "location" parameter for queryautocomplete command in Google Maps API. But whatever coordinates I give, it returns the same results. I just need to get search suggestions of places nearby the location coordinates. Here is query example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82&key=*******&location=53.2415041,50.22124629999996&language=ru
**** is key ID

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**дружба**

> define a radius too.

Currently you get a place in moskow as first result, although the location is in samara(but the returned places are more prominent , e.g. **mir prospect** in moscow)

Sample request with radius a radius of 50km:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82&location=53.2415041,50.22124629999996&radius=50000&key=yourkey

First result: **lenin prospect, samara**

Comment: Yes, I really forgot to specify the "radius". I am sorry for my stupid question.